# jQuery assistance needed with mouseover() and slideDown

Tags: jquery, html, css

so I'm trying to work on some little stuff with HTML, CSS, & jQuery. One of the things which I'm trying to do is to make a div slide down whenever I have the mouse over it. The code that I have right now looks like:

```
$(document.ready(function(){
     $('div').mouseover(function(){
           $('div').slideDown('slow');
     };
     $('div').mouseout(function(){
           $('div').slideUp('slow');
     });
});
```

However, for some reason, this does not seem to work. Assume that everything is linked properly, and that the CSS and everything else is coded correctly. It only starts to goof when the mouseover() and mouseout() are in the code. Can someone tell me why? I can get this to work when there is a 'trigeger' div on top of the other, so that when the mouse hovers over the 'trigger' div, the one on the bottom slides down. Any help with making one div slide down would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot a `)` at line 4 so the handler is never closing

Comment: @Frederik.L even with the parenthesis, the code doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please see my updated answer, I added a short explanation of why it doesn't work the way you want and edited your fiddle. Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously reported, there is a closing parenthesis missing at the end of the first handler.

Inside your handlers, you should use `$(this)` which references to the element that fired the event rather than *all divs of the document*:

```
$(document.ready(function(){
     $('div').mouseover(function(){
           $(this).slideDown('slow');
     });
     $('div').mouseout(function(){
           $(this).slideUp('slow');
     });
});
```

I also recommend that you handle a more specific selector than `div`... with such a confusing selector you reduce your page to a "cannot change anything"-state. With a markup like this:

```
<div class="hover-effect">
    <!--  content -->
</div>
```

You could have something like this:

```
$('.hover-effect').mouseover(/* ... */);
$('.hover-effect').mouseout(/* ... */);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

According to the jsfiddle you provided, you are basically trying to handle the mouseover event on a div that isn't displayed. Your code works exactly as expected. If you play baseball, you will surely have an epic time trying to hit the ball while it hasn't been thrown yet.

First, you need a container that will always have some width and height. One way to ensure this can be to set a top padding to the container. Inside that container, your slider can slide as you wish without reaching the "nothing"-state. For the benefits of a free pointer effect, I assumed that it is intended to be displayed as a link.

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<a class="slider-container" href="#">
    <div class="slider"></div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider-container {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    padding-top:25px;
    background-color:#000000;
}

.slider {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#000000;
    display:none;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $slider_container=$('.slider-container');

    $slider_container.mouseover(function(){
        $('.slider',this).stop().slideDown('slow');
    });

    $slider_container.mouseout(function(){
        $('.slider',this).stop().slideUp("slow");
    });
});
```

Take a look at this working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4CdFP/11/)

Comment: @ak34_ What happends is that to fire a mouse event, an element must have a displayable size in which the engine can calculate whether the cursor position fits in. If the container has no height, scrolling the inner div up will lead to the same problem. If the container has a specific height, it is not clear which behavior is wanted when setting a bigger height to the inner. IE will more likely take bad decisions. The padding was a workaround to ensure it has a minimum height without restricting it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parentheses on the `mouseover()`

```
$(document.ready(function(){
     $('div').mouseover(function(){
           $('div').slideDown('slow');
     });
     $('div').mouseout(function(){
           $('div').slideUp('slow');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Frederik has noted, you can't target something that is hidden in the DOM. A simplified answer would be to have another element which acts as a trigger for the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events, like this:

HTML

```
<div id="trigger">Hover Me</div>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

CSS

```
#slider {
  display: none; /* etc */
}
```

jQuery

```
    $("#trigger").mouseover(function(){
        $('#slider').slideDown("slow");
    });
    $("#trigger").mouseout(function(){
        $('#slider').slideUp("slow");
    });
```